# Tracking unpaid voluntary effort in open source projects

Tags: open-source, time-tracking

I am curious if any open source project actually tracked effort by a measure like self-reported hours put by unpaid voluntary coders. Do they? How? Why?

I don't care for cost estimations functions of SLOC or any other nonsense variable.

I suggest as answer an example with multiple contributors with a explanation of how and why they do that.

Comment: _"Is there any open source project ..."_ -- Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Programmers as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I would like to have phrased it as "has been done" or "do they". I accept suggestions or perhaps I should remove "is there any" so people don't think the question in simplistic terms.

Comment: "as an unpaid voluntary coder (in open source), why would I need to track hours..." - that would probably have better chances to fly, either at Programmers or at TWP, or better yet at PM.SE

Comment: Isn't that kinda what [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/) is about?

Comment: If you mean COCOMO model, that is what I meant for "cost estimation function of SLOC". I think it is pointless to try to put a price on the whole code base, I just wonder what is contributed monthly measured by something else than lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it.  Most software developers see time tracking activities as an evil necessary to functioning within a business.  It's extremely unlikely someone would do it when they don't have to.

Comment: I can only see time tracking as a good thing if it's a voluntary exercise, done once in a while mainly for the benefit of the programmer so they can figure out how over or under their own time estimates are. Otherwise yah, it's the worst necessary evil.